# How to eliminate stacks in screen switching

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I have a few screens that I need to switch between using the `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter when I tap on the Icons.

I'm calling the different screens in a List widget below:

```
List<Widget> pages = [
    const Dashboard(),
    const HomePage(checklistData: [], numberofForms: 0, userData: {},),
    const ScannerPage(title: 'Scan QR Code',),
    const Notifications(),
    const Login(),

  ];
```

However, this is the output when I click on one Icon to call up the screen that I need:

[Stacked Up Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwI6v.png)

The first `AppBar` with "Maintenance Checklist" is from the screen I'm calling.
The second `AppBar` with "Welcome back, Agent Wesley!" is from the `Dashboard()` screen which should be disappearing when calling the Checklist screen.

How do I make sure that the content of the screen I call is what appears on that screen not all content from other screens?

Here is my `Scaffold` from `Dashboard()` that I think is causing the problem:

```
      backgroundColor: Constants.primaryColor,
      body: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          pages.elementAt(activeIndex),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: kToolbarHeight,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 16.0,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            FlutterIcons.keyboard_backspace_mdi,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Welcome back,\n",
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .headline6
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Agent Wesley!",
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .headline6
                                        ?.copyWith(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200.0,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      color: Constants.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 24.0,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            "Agent Services",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(19, 22, 33, 1),
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 7.0),
                        Container(
                         height: 100.0,
                          child: const Center(
                            // lets make a widget for the cards
                            //child: ServiceSlider(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use navigator (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)
or use PageView (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)